# How to recover a valuation from a satifsiable formula, a question about model

Tags: z3

I'm using Z3 with the ml interface. I had created a formula 
f(x_i)
that is satisfiable, according to the solver
`Solver.mk_simple_solver ctx`r.

The problem is: I can get a model, but he find me values only for some variables of the formula, and not all (some of my `Model.get_const_interp_e`r  end with a type None)

How can it be possible that the model can give me only a part  of the `x_i`r? In my understanding, if the model work for one of the values, it means that the formula was satisfiable (in my case, it is) and so all the values can be given...

I don't understand something..
Thanks for reading me!

Answer (score 0):

You should always post full examples so people can help with actual coding issues; without seeing your actual code, it's impossible to know what might be the actual reason.

Having said that, this sounds very much like the following question: [Why Z3Py does not provide all possible solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162290/why-z3py-does-not-provide-all-possible-solutions/53163796#53163796) So, perhaps the answer given there will help you.

Long story short: Z3 models will only contain values for variables that *matter* for the model. For anything that is not explicitly assigned, any value will do. There are ways to get "full" models as explained in that answer of course; which I'm sure is also possible from the ML interface.