# while enumerating Z3 solutions, model does not give value for variable

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I'm new to using Z3 but I am seeing some strange behavior when trying to enumerate solutions to a set of boolean constraints.  My code is below:

```
from z3 import Bool, Xor, Or, And, Not, Solver, sat

x0 = Bool("x0")
x1 = Bool("x1")
x2 = Bool("x2")
x3 = Bool("x3")

solver = Solver()
solver.add(Xor(x0, x1))
solver.add(Xor(Or(x2, x0), Not(x3)))

while solver.check() == sat:
    model = solver.model()
    print()
    print(solver)
    print(model)
    cons = Or([d() != model[d] for d in model])
    solver.add(cons)
```

Which outputs

```
[Xor(x0, x1), Xor(Or(x2, x0), Not(x3))]
[x3 = False, x2 = False, x1 = True, x0 = False]

[Xor(x0, x1),
 Xor(Or(x2, x0), Not(x3)),
 Or(x3 != False, x2 != False, x1 != True, x0 != False)]
[x3 = True, x1 = False, x0 = True]

[Xor(x0, x1),
 Xor(Or(x2, x0), Not(x3)),
 Or(x3 != False, x2 != False, x1 != True, x0 != False),
 Or(x3 != True, x1 != False, x0 != True)]
[x3 = True, x2 = True, x1 = True, x0 = False]
```

You can see that the second model gives `[x3 = True, x1 = False, x0 = True]` with no reference to the value of `x2` even though `x2` clearly has constraints in the solver.

Comment: Or(Whatever, True) -> True, right? This eliminates x2

Comment: But Or(x3 != False, x2 != False, x1 != True, x0 != False) should not eliminate any one variable, necessarily.  It just means one of them must change.

Comment: In your source `x2` only goes into `Or(x2, x0)` . Solver says `x0=True` this is effectively then `Or(x2, True)` and that simplifies into just `True`.

Comment: Try it yourself. Take solver's solution and then test two cases - one with x2=False and another one with x2=True.

Comment: That `Or` you are referring to is nested in an `Xor` so I don't think it's that simple.  Even assuming it is 'eliminated' shouldn't the model still give some result?  Can I force that?  My goal is to iterate over all solutions so I would like to force an answer.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "force". Whenever you get solution without a variable - you are free to use whatever in that place. Just always use False, or True.

Comment: use SimpleSolver then instead. It  prints for me all possible solutions including redundant ones.

Comment: Can you give some example code?  I don't see many docs for that.  But anyway I figured a way to do it in my answer.

Comment: Replace `solver = Solver()` with `solver = SimpleSolver()` and it will output what you want.

Comment: That fixes the second case though the final case still excludes x2

Comment: This is output which I get: `{x0: False, x1: True, x2: False, x3: False}
{x0: False, x1: True, x2: True, x3: True}
{x0: True, x1: False, x2: True, x3: True}
{x0: True, x1: False, x2: False, x3: True}
`
all the vars are in place.

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved by using `model_completion` in order to fill an arbitrary value for a free variable.

```
from z3 import Bool, Xor, Or, And, Not, Solver, sat

x0 = Bool("x0")
x1 = Bool("x1")
x2 = Bool("x2")
x3 = Bool("x3")
refs = [x0, x1, x2, x3]

solver = Solver()
solver.add(Xor(x0, x1))
solver.add(Xor(Or(x2, x0), Not(x3)))

while solver.check() == sat:
    model = solver.model()
    print({d: model.eval(d, model_completion=True) for d in refs})
    cons = Or([d != model.eval(d, model_completion=True) for d in refs])
    solver.add(cons)
```

```
{x0: False, x1: True, x2: False, x3: False}
{x0: False, x1: True, x2: True, x3: True}
{x0: True, x1: False, x2: False, x3: True}
{x0: True, x1: False, x2: True, x3: True}
```

Comment: This has been discussed on SO before. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162290/why-z3py-does-not-provide-all-possible-solutions for instance.